# How to use [Authorize] to authenticate token returned by API?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

guys!

Currently, I get a Bearer Token from an API.
What I want to do is:

- Get token from external API
- Use .NET [Authorize] in controller
- Compare token returned from API with token informed in Authorization Header of request
- If they are equal, authorize the request
- If they are not equal, return 401

What's the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

After using `[Authorize]`attribute in your controller class; 3rd, 4th and 5th steps automatically performed by .NET built-in functions.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the asp.net core provide the build-in authentication schema to authenticate the JWT bear token.

You could put the right settings inside the registered service with the right secret and issuer settings, then your application will check the token and set the claims into your application to achieve the authentication.

More details about how it works, you could refer to this [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/bearer-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core/).

Answer (score 0):

If JTW is the only way you are authenticating endpoints, it should be as "simple" as;

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options => {
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options => {
    options.SaveToken = true;
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = "..TODO..",
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = "..TODO..",
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(..TODO..);
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But how could I retrieve the current token from an external API and expect this token to be entered?

Comment: Ah, so you are going to keep the token in a cookie / session / database table related to an existing logged in user?

Comment: Something like that. The fact is: I have a service that handles login. I'm creating another service that will handle other tools. But those tools needs to be authenticated. I want to know if the logged user is using its current login, because JWT key changes everyday in login service. So I will call the login service to get JWT key each day and compare with token entered by user to know if their login is current.